# How to change each element's content that are in one class using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, class, foreach, currency

hope someone can help me with this.
I have content where are 30 elements of one class.

I need to change each of that element with `click(function(){...` method, for example I click on a button.

The value of each element should be, let's say, value before * 2;

Here is part of my html:

```
<p>from <span class="currency">69.95</span></p>
<p>Economy Worldwide - above <span class="currency">65.05</span></p><p>Express Worldwide - above <span class="currency">195.15</span></p>
```

Thank you for your assistance.

Comment: Have you tried anything yet?

Comment: You want to click on *one* and change all 30 elements' value?

Comment: The value must be equal for all elements?

Comment: Yes, I tried, to get numbers from .currency content with parseFloat($('.currency').text().replace(/([^0-9\\.])/g,""));

Answer (score 4):

I'd do it in the following way:

```
$("button").click(function() {
    $(".currency").text(function(i, val) {
        return val * 2;
    });
});
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/eGxAV/

Comment: Don't forget to parse that number :)

Comment: @mattytommo No need. Multiplication will do it implicitly.

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest:

```
$('.currency').click(function(){
    $('.currency').text(function(i,t){
        return parseFloat(t * 2).toFixed(2);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$('button').click(function () {
    $('span.currency').each(function () {
        var newVal = $(this).text() * 2;
        $(this).text(newVal.toFixed(2));
    });
});
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/UNPpL/)**